# Overwriting file with Dropbox API

Tags: android, dropbox

I'm having trouble implementing a dropbox backup to my app. I wan't the every next backup to overwrite previous one.

I tried this first:

```
newEntry = mDBApi.putFile("/file.bak", inputStream, file.length(), null, null);
```

It was creating test.bak and then test.bak(1) test.bak(2) and so on...

then I tried to save the revision id of the first file, and then pass it to every upload.

```
newEntry = mDBApi.putFile("/file.bak", inputStream, file.length(), revision, null);
```

I get file.bak and then file.bak (conflicted copy.... ) and so on

What am I doing wrong? Dropbox documentation says that the conflicted copy appears when 2 users try to upload the same file on the same time, but it's not happening right here

EDIT: I can workaround it by deleting file 1st, but that doesn't sound too proffesional

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just take a look at the [Dropbox API](https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.5.1-docs/).

It provides a method for overwriting an existing file (with the same filename): [putFileOverwrite](https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.5.1-docs/com/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI.html#putFileOverwrite%28java.lang.String,%20java.io.InputStream,%20long,%20com.dropbox.client2.ProgressListener%29)

Or, if you want to be able to cancel the upload, create a [putFileOverwriteRequest](https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.5.1-docs/com/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI.html#putFileOverwriteRequest%28java.lang.String,%20java.io.InputStream,%20long,%20com.dropbox.client2.ProgressListener%29) and kick it off by calling `upload()`.

Comment: which class's object `mDBApi` is ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
      try {
            DropboxAPI.Entry newEntry = mDBApi.putFileOverwrite("/file.bak", inputStream, file.length(), null);
        } catch (DropboxUnlinkedException e) {
            Log.e("DbExampleLog", "User has unlinked.");
        } catch (DropboxException e) {
            Log.e("DbExampleLog", "Something went wrong while uploading.");
        }
```